# Determine active Page Object within Typo3

Tags: typo3

I'm writing a plugin which should add HTML to the page's head area (inludeJS to be exact). Something like this should work:

```
page.includeJS {
  tx_myplugin_pi1 = EXT:my_plugin/pi1/tx_myplugin_fe_scripts.js
}
```

The problem with that is that I have to assume that "page" would be the universal name used for the page object I want to work with. Since the name of this variable can be anything I would like to do this in a more intelligent way than this.

Is there a way to determine the name of the current PAGE cObject I'm working with?

cu
Roman

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the default `PAGE` object of the current page using this snippet:

```
$setup = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup; 
foreach(array_keys($setup) as $key){
    if(substr($key, -1) == '.'){
        if($setup[substr($key,0,-1)] === 'PAGE' && intval($setup[$key]['typeNum']) === 0){
            print substr($key,0,-1) .' is the default PAGE object';
        }
    }
}
```

But this won't help you to add the Javascript in the frontend, as the typoscript is being parsed already at that point.

If you want to add the javascript just for your extension I would recommend using:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData['tx_yourextension_plugin'] = '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . t3lib_extMgm::siteRelPath('my_plugin') . 'pi1/tx_myplugin_fe_scripts.js"></script>';
```

(this wouldn't be merged with the other JS files though)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no such way in plain TypoScript. As most installations are using `page` as keyword - especially those which are under your control - it is really fine to use it.

If you are writing an extension, you can put that into the documentation as a small hint!